# Модель данных в ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Разбираюсь с ember.js, и не могу разобраться с моделями. Есть модель `player`, это список игроков. Мне нужна модель `team`, каждый элемент которой будет записью модели `player`. Как сказать что они связаны? Можно ли как то ограничить размер модели? Например так, что бы количество записей в модели `team`, не превышало пяти.

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/defining-models/#toc_defining-relationships - ознакомься в первую очередь, здесь хорошо рассказано, как определять отношения. По поводу ограничения размера не знаю, но едва ли это вообще должно определяться в модели.

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).